# Parsing a 6 digit number into a 6 int array

Tags: c#, java, parsing, int

I want to be able to parse a a six digit number and take each character and place in an array for example: `"738593" -> d[1] = 7, d[2] = 3. d[3] = 8`....etc

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] d = new int[10];
    d1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s.charAt(0)));
    d3 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s.charAt(1)));
    d2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s.charAt(2))); //JAVA LINE
    ...
}
```

I found a line from Java that does exactly what I want but I was looking around for a C# equivalent. Any ideas?

Comment: One line of code is hardly 'parsing' or an 'algorithm'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
int[] d = s.Select(c => (int)c - (int)'0').ToArray();
```

What you are doing here is iterating over each of the characters in the string, converting them to a stream of integers (`IEnumerable<int>`) then making that stream into an array. This requires C# 3.0 and LINQ.

Alternatively you could try:

```
int[] d = s.Select(c => int.Parse(c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

which will throw an exception if the string being passed in is not a string of digits, but may have some performance penalty as for each character in the string a further string is made.

Both these method will work on digit strings of any size*.

<sup>*that can be stored in memory of course.</sup>

Comment: Same problem as Lee's answer: `(int)'0'` isn't 0.

Comment: Yep, just spotted it, changed it just as you mentioned it.

Comment: Looks good to me now. Unlike what's in the question, this will not throw an exception if non-digits are present. If the input values are already validated, that won't matter.

Comment: Again, spotted that and edited the question same time you did ;p. I just can't type fast enough :p

Comment: You don't need the cast: `c - '0'` alone works, beacuse `char` is considered to be a numeric type.

Comment: That is true, but I decided to make it explicit as the people who are going to be needing an answer for this might get confused by subtraction on characters, maybe thinking `'3' - '2' = '1'` for example.

Comment: Yeah. The result would be an `int`. Type `?('5'-'2').GetType().Name` + <enter> into the immediate window of VS. You will get `"Int32"` as result.

Comment: Yep, I understand. I what trying to get at is that it may be difficult for the reader who doesn't understand that types don't have to be closed under binary operations in C#, ie <int> - <int> can equal something other than <int>, which isn't really a natural assumption. So I made it explicit. You're totally right though, and if I were writing the code I would use your method :)

Answer (score 2):

In c#, that will be:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] d = new int[10];
    d1 = int.Parse(s[0].ToString());
    d3 = int.Parse(s[1].ToString());
    d2 = int.Parse(s[2].ToString());
    ...
}
```

It may work without the `.ToString()` but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's still more complicated than necessary, but unlike the other answers, yours is actually correct... except for what you copied from the question, and was incorrect there (`d1`, `d3` and `d2` instead of `d[0]`, `d[1]` and `d[2]`).

Comment: for loop is probably a better choice than listing out each item individually anyway.

Comment: I just translated what he got from Java so he can understand the differences between both languages for doing the same.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But he was looking just for the c# equivalent

Comment: Well this should work well except I keep getting an error (Index was outside the bounds of the array.) Any ideas?

Comment: @Marshal: Either your input string is small for all the `s[x]` statements you have written or `d` is too small for the same reason. Have a look at my answer for a solution that does not depend on the size of the input string.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing I can think of is converting it into a chararray:

```
char[] val = s.toCharArray();
```

Since the char datatype is just integers this shouldn't be a problem, and also I think you could do:

```
int[] val = s.toCharArray();
```

But I'm not entirerly sure about that so no promises about that one :)

Comment: No, that won't work, and even if it would, it would not do what the question asks. The question asks for `{ 7, 3, 8, 5, 9, 3 }`, not `{ '7', '3', '8', '5', '9', '3' }`. Note that not only the types are different, also the numerical values.

Comment: Ummm yeah, that was really stupid of me. Let the downvotes hail.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
int x=654321;
string[] stringarray=x.toString().split('');
```

Comment: he wants the result as an int array, so you'd need to cast the individual characters

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] d = new int[6];
for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
    d[i] = Int32.Parse(s[i]);
}
```

This is how you parse Strings to ints in c#

Answer (score 1):

May be if you convert directly you might get the asii values try something like this:

```
char[] val = 738593.ToString().ToCharArray().ToArray();
```

where the to string might avoid converting each digit to the asii value.

Answer (score 1):

```
static public int[] StringToIntArray(string input)
{
    List<int> tempList = new List<int>();
    foreach (char c in input)
    {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        {
            tempList.Add(c - '0');
        }
    }
    return tempList.ToArray();
}
```

Note that this will completely ignore any non-digits. So if your input is `"867ASDF5309"`, the int array will come out as `{ 8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9 }`